# Why do we use 'new' keyword with primitive data types like `boolean`, to create array?

Tags: java

In java, the two data types are reference types and primitive types. Reference types are references to objects while primitive types directly contain values.

now, the `new` keyword in java is used to create the instance of an Object, for example,

```
String s3 = new String("foo")
```

or

```
String[] myStringArray = new String[3];
```

This is ok because `String` is a class and not a primitive data type.

but since `boolean` or `int` are primitive data types, why do we use `new` keyword with them when creating an array,

```
int[] myIntArray = new int[3];
int[] myIntArray = new int[]{1,2,3};
boolean[] array = new boolean[size];
```

Shouldn't `new` keyword be only use with reference data types ?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Because when you do `int[] myIntArray = new int[3];` you are *creating an array*.. And an array is *also an Object*.

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    int[] arr = new int[5];
    System.out.println(arr instanceof Object);
}
```

O/P :

```
true
```

EDIT :

If you look at the byte code, you will have this call for new int[5]

`1: newarray   int` and `newarray` is defined [here](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Java_bytecode_instruction_listings).

So, basically the compiler is hiding the truth from you :P

Comment: so you are implying that adding square brackets `[]` will make primitive data types to behave like an Object of Array ?

Comment: @bhuvesh no, there is an _additional_ datetype (array) that is created by using [ ]. You can find this out by doing: arr.getClass().isArray()

Comment: @bhuvesh the array type is a type itself, and it is a reference type. nativetype[] refers to an array type just the same as objecttype[] does.

Comment: thank you, i know what array is...one question `int` is primitive data type while `int []` is entirely different type (reference type) ?

Comment: thank you for the bytecode example..now it makes more sense to me :)

Answer (score 3):

The new keyword refers to the array you create. In fact,

> In the Java programming language, arrays are objects, are dynamically
>   created, and may be assigned to variables of type Object. All methods
>   of class Object may be invoked on an array.

Check [this](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se7/html/jls-10.html) for more details

Answer (score 2):

array is `reference` type therefor you need to use `new` operator to create it.

Answer (score 0):

Arrays are objects that can be assigned to a variable of type Object